# C# Referencing the value of a variable

Tags: c#

I'm having difficulty understanding how I can reference the return value of a variable to create another in C#.

```
string name = Console.ReadLine();

List<Thing> name = new List<Thing>();
```

For example, user inputs "Cats" and thus a new list Cats is created.

Or in this scenario:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
 {
    List<Thing> (animal + i) = new List<Thing>();
 }
```

Where the lists created becomes animal0, animal1, animal2... etc.

Thank you

Comment: You want to accept the string `"Cats"` as input and then create a `List<Cat>`? Or you want to _name_ a different variable based on the user input?

Comment: Maybe there is a specific tutorial or book you are following where you are not quite understanding the material? If it is online maybe you can share a link which can help clarify what it is you are not understanding...

Comment: You should back up a step or two and research how a `List<T>` works

Comment: I agree that you are probably misunderstanding what you are being asked to do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in C# at least not naturally.

Variable are determined at the compile time.

Value you are talking about (Cats, animal0, ...) are determined at the runtime, when the code is really running, which occurs after the compilation. So those values cannot become variable names.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create variables dynamically at runtime, so every variable you would like to use needs to be declared on compile time. Nevertheless, a `List<Thing>` can hold multiple instances of a `Thing` at the same time, representing - in your sense - multiple variables.

For example:

```
var things = new List<Thing>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  things.Add(new Cat()); // if Cat derives from Thing
}

// access the list items by index
Console.WriteLine(thing[0]);
Console.WriteLine(thing[1]);
...
```